# Chart.js bar chart coming up as blank with smaller datasets

Tags: javascript, chart.js

```js
new Chart(
    document.getElementById('chart'),
    {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'Conversions',
                    data: [0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true                   
                },
                x: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }
        }
    }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.1.1/chart.umd.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"> </canvas>
```

I have a Chart.js bar chart that is loaded dynamically. Depending on the data the chart will be blank, even if there is data to be displayed. Here is an example of the chart instantiation, with the data variable being replaced by a sample input that creates a blank chart.
It seems like charts with less data are more likely to display blank. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed labels array in the data. You have to define labels (same length of data). And you can see the results.
(Hint: I suggest that set `maintainAspectRatio` as `true`)

Here is the working example:

```js
const data = [0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]


const charts = document.getElementById("chart1");
  new Chart(
    charts,
    {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: Array.from('x'.repeat(data.length-1)), // you can five any labels array you want
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Conversions',
            data: data
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            suggestedMin: 0,
            suggestedMax: 1
          },
        }
      }
    }
  );
```

Comment: Thanks! I was passing it an associative array which worked because my top value was '90+'. For smaller ranges it was treated as a regular array, so I just had to make sure I was passing it an associative array every time